# Copied sheet with macro - reference issue in office 2013

Tags: vba, excel

There's a file that has few macros in it. **Person A** uses macro, which copies one sheet (with button in it with another macro attached to it) and sends it **person B** as an attachment via Outlook. 
 
When person B tries to run macro from received file it says macro is missing (macro from Person's B file has reference to file from person A).

Problem started when users switched to Office 2013. It used to work well in 2010.

Macro from Person's A essentially does only this:

```
ws1.Visible = True 
ws1.Copy
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Range("F8:F45").Locked = False
ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "file_name" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

and later on:

```
   .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName
```

Thanks in advance for any input on this matter.

Comment: Have you checked if a normal "export-import" of the sheet by hand is working for you with the new version?

Comment: Look at saving the workbook first and then attaching the copy.

Comment: @DavidG I've tried doing it manually and macro has reference to old file.

Comment: As a way around - instead of copying sheet and saving it as new file I deleted all other sheets and then saved it.